# Unsupported data type "TEXT" when using databrick jdbc driver to write

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, databricks-sql

Caused by: com.databricks.client.support.exceptions.ErrorException: [Databricks]DatabricksJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error running query: [UNSUPPORTED_DATATYPE] org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:
[UNSUPPORTED_DATATYPE] Unsupported data type "TEXT".(line 1, pos 37)

The problem shows when I tried to ingress data into from sql server into databrick using jdbc driver. Is there anyway around this? Thanks

Comment: please provide more information - SQL statement, driver version, etc.

Comment: Drivers: mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar and DatabricksJDBC42.jar
SQL Statements : CREATE TABLE DIMCUSTOMER ("Customer" TEXT , "Name" TEXT , "ShortName" TEXT ,...